# Url rewriting not worked properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I have two rules as follows..

```
<rule source="Admission/Undergraduate/Selection-Criteria" destination="HomePageContents/Selection_Criteria99.aspx" />

<rule source="Admission/Undergraduate/Selection-Criteria/Application-Requirement" destination="HomePageContents/Application_Requirement103.aspx" />
```

but when I want to navigate to `'Admission/Undergraduate/Selection-Criteria/Application-Requirement '` I got an error

> 'Requested URL:
>   /TestDomain/HomePageContents/Selection_Criteria99.aspx/Application-Requirement'

Actually I want to write my rule source as it exact match the source then redirect.

Please resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying two things. First, try re-ordering the two rules so that the longer URL matches first.

Second, make the shorter source URL more specific with the regex metacharacter '`$`':

```
<rule source="Admission/Undergraduate/Selection-Criteria$" destination="HomePageContents/Selection_Criteria99.aspx" />
```

The '`$`' is [end-of-line metacharacter](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Metacharacters). By using this, you instruct the rule engine that anything after `/Selection-Criteria` is **not** a match.